# C# delegate and event in UserControl

Tags: c#, .net

I have UserControl similar to ListView. I want to create event machining delete item from ListView.

I doing so. But I do not know how to go on.

```
    public partial class ImagesSetEditor : UserControl
{
    public delegate void ImageRemovedEventHandler(object sender, ImagesSetEditor e);
    public event ImageRemovedEventHandler ImageRemovedEvent;
```

Comment: If you want to extend `ListView` functionality you should inherit from it. Otherwise you'll have to create your own logic to rise event.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a new delegate for conforming with the event based pattern. Create a simple event in your control as such:

```
public event EventHandler ImageRemoved;
```

if you need any custom arugments passed on, create a class that derives from `EventArgs` as such:

```
public class ImageRemovedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
     public int Index; //for example
}
```

and then declare the event as such:

```
public event EventHandler<ImageRemovedEventArgs> ImageRemoved;
```

You would then fire the event as such:

```
if (ImageRemoved != null) ImageRemoved(this, new ImageRemovedEventArgs() { Index = yourValue });
```

It is important to check that `ImageRemoved != null`, because it will throw an exception if the event has no subscribers.

Comment: Thank. But but how to pass index in UserControl or Form?

Comment: @guxago Sorry, I don't understand your question. Please try to explain.

Comment: In UserControl I have variable int remove_index. How I can do that remove_index =Index ?

Comment: in the `ImageRemovedEventArgs` constructor just set `Index` to `remove_index` or whatever value you have.